# Micsoroft Enterprise Validation framework -> How to have one config file per validated Type

Tags: app-config, enterprise-library

I am using microsoft enterprise validation framework. And I'm linking the file 'validation.config' in my app.config file.

```
<section name="validation"    type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Configuration.ValidationSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" restartOnExternalChanges="false"  />

<validation configSource="LocalConfiguration\validation.config" />
```

In 'validation.config' file i have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<validation>
    <type name="Car">
     <ruleset>
      <properties>
       <validators>...</validators>
      </properties>
     </ruleset>
    </type>
    <type name="Human">
     <ruleset>
      <properties>
       <validators>...</validators>
      </properties>
     </ruleset>
    </type>
</validation>
```

The question is: Can i put the 'Car' and 'Human' types in different files and link those files in validation.config or is there any other way of separation because my validators are too many and I want it to be clean and easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

[@.NETJunkie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/) has a blog post on [Splitting up Validation Application Block configuration into multiple files](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=72) which should address your needs.